# Riemann series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\omega=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ admits a limit in $\infty$ and to calculate it. I dont even know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $n \mapsto n^{-x}$ is decreasing for $x > 0$, it follows that
$$
1 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x} \le 1 + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}\,dn = 1 + \frac{1}{x-1}
$$
for $x > 1$. Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x} = 1.
$$